# whenever i try to rebuild project it gave the error of compilation failed to complete in android studio

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-studio-3.0

when i rebuild my project after clean project option it always stop and gave error of compilation failed to complete
and here are some detail of that error i can't able to to fix that please help me

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\MOEEZ AHMAD\Desktop\HDWALLPAPER\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    ... 56 more
```

these are the error showing due to which my rebuild is not completing please guide me 
i tried every possible thing to remove that error but all is waste of time so thats why i am posting my question here i also read many question over here but not getting my answer currently i am use android studio 3.1.1 please help me

Comment: Could you find the solution ?

Comment: yes i fix that issue by the help below in the comments

Comment: tnx. I'll check that.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `multiDexEnabled` to `true` in your app's build.gradle file, under `defaultConfig`. For example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir for great guide line my issue solved thank you very much sir

Comment: it again started to give the same error multiDexEnabled is already set to true what should i do now? @nope4561759

Comment: it again started to give the same error multiDexEnabled is already set to true this time it is giving this " Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}"  what should i do now? @nope4561759